# Change stock email notifications recipient in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, email-notifications

I want to change stock email recipient email address in woocommerce. Already changes admin email but mails are still going to old email.

Comment: Have you checked -  Notification Recipient – Enter email address for notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparently has to be done in the database directly as there is no backend option to change this and woocommerce apparently simply uses the admin e-mail address from the time it's installed. simply search the table wp_options (or different if you chose another prefix than wp_ for your tables) for the option_name: woocommerce_stock_email_recipient and change it to the new one.

Comment: I have already told that this is one of the possible way to change the email address of stock email recipient.. Thanks for answering it again

Comment: When product no stock, notification email send to admin & vendor email id! i add only admin email to inventory section but don't know how vendor also get notification email Do you have any idea ? please advise

Answer (score 34):

This can be set at the Woocommerce settings page.

Admin -> Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Inventory

Its a bit hidden but its there.

Comment: This should be the new updated accepted answer. No DB change needed.

Comment: When product no stock, notification email send to admin & vendor email id! i add only admin email to inventory section but don't know how vendor also get notification email Do you have any idea ? please advise

Answer (score 5):

To change stock email recipient, try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_backorder', 'change_stock_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // For Backorders notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_low_stock', 'change_stock_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // For Low stock notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_no_stock', 'change_stock_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // For No stock notification
function change_stock_email_recipient( $recipient, $product ) {
    // HERE set your replacement email
    $recipient = 'thename@email.com';

    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Hey, it worked too but i have changed it with database wp_options table option name -> "woocommerce_stock_email_recipient"... Thanks for you help :)

Comment: this apparently can't be set in woocommerce and has to bet set in the database... at least I didn't find it ANYWHERE in the woo backend so I also did it in the database ... very stupid.

Comment: When product no stock, notification email send to admin & vendor email id! i add only admin email to inventory section but don't know how vendor also get notification email Do you have any idea ? please advise

Answer (score 4):

Admin -> Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Inventory

Comment: When product no stock, notification email send to admin & vendor email id! i add only admin email to inventory section but don't know how vendor also get notification email Do you have any idea ? please advise